# What the difference between route53 geolocation and geoproximity routing policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

In Youtube AWS video course it says that

Geolocation routing policy - allow you to direct traffic based on geographic location of where the request originated from
( as i understand if i have ALB in 2 regions ( US and Brazil ) The users from USA are redirected to ALB in US, and users in Brazil are redirected to Brazil located ALB

Geoproximity routing policy - allow you to direct traffic based on geographic location of your users and your aws resources

for me it's sounds the same, can you explain it using real-world cases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both Geolocation and Geoproximity routing policies route traffic based on the geographic location of the users and server resources. Geoproximity routing policy additionally allows you to route more or less traffic to certain resources by specifying a value, known as a bias. Geoproximity can be understood as allocating more influence to some resources in desired regions based on the bias.

For example, you have web servers in London(England) and Frankfurt(Germany). A user originates from France. The geolocation policy will redirect this user to London region because the geolocation of France is closer to the London. Now if you have allocated more capacity to your Frankfurt resources and you want to redirect more traffic of Europe mainland to Frankfurt, then you can use Geoproximity routing polity. You can set more bias to the Frankfurt region by setting up the traffic flow.

Please check more details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy-geoproximity.html

Comment: Note that when learning for a certification (SysOps for example) always read carefully if routing should be done based on location of users (geolocation) or resources (geoproximity). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html